# Поиск приближенного числа в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить поиск приближенного числа. Допустим есть массив [1 5 2 4 9], искомое число 6, если его нет в массиве то нужно найти близкое меньшее к нему (это 4). Поиск осуществляю в массиве old по полю olds.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Возраст" id="age"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Зрелость" id="maturity"><br>
<button onclick="inputData()">Обучить</button>
<hr>
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите свой возраст" id="myAge"><br>
<button onclick="myMaturity()">Узнать свою зрелость</button>

var old = [
{
    olds: 1,
    mature: "Молодой"
},
{
    olds: 30,
    mature: "Зрелый"
},
{
    olds: 60,
    mature: "Старый"
}
];

function inputData() {

    var a = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('maturity').value;

        old.push({
            olds: a,
            mature: b
        });
        console.log(old);
}

function myMaturity () {
    var a1 = document.getElementById('myAge').value;

        for (var key in old) {
            if (old[key].olds <= a1) {
                console.log(old[key].mature);
            } 
        }

}
```

Comment: что значит _приближенное число_?

Comment: Допустим есть массив [1 5 2 4 9], искомое число 6, если его нет в массиве то нужно найти близкое к нему (это 4 и 5).

Comment: и какое из этих двух чисел нужно вернуть? 4 или 5 или оба?

Comment: В этом случае требовалось бы найти 4, невнимательно описал вопрос когда писал тему, извиняйте.

Comment: стоит его отредактировать с помощью кнопки [edit].

Comment: Исправил, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var delta = 999, itemId = -1; 
for (var key in old) {
    if (Math.abs(old[key].olds - a1) < delta) {
        itemId = key;
        delta = Math.abs(old[key].olds - a1);            
    } 
}

var near = old[itemId]; // <= тот элемент, который нам нужен
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Извените что не сразу спросил, но не могли бы вы объяснить для чего используется delta?

Comment: @user220343, из кода же видно. Для поиска наименьшего значения между возрастом и массивом возрастов. Где разница меньше, то значение и ближе

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я так и думал но хотел удостоверится в правильности своего довода.

Answer (score 0):

если массив сортировать, то последний элемент удовлетворющий условию *old[key].olds <= a1* будет искомым

```js
 var old = [{
   olds: 1,
   mature: "Молодой"
 }, {
   olds: 30,
   mature: "Зрелый"
 }, {
   olds: 60,
   mature: "Старый"
 }];

 function inputData() {

   var a = document.getElementById('age').value;
   var b = document.getElementById('maturity').value;
   old.push({
     olds: a,
     mature: b
   });
 }

 function myMaturity() {
   var a1 = document.getElementById('myAge').value;
   var mature = old.filter(a => a.olds <= a1).sort((a, b) => a.olds - b.olds).pop().mature;
   console.log(mature);
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Возраст" id="age">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Зрелость" id="maturity">
<br>
<button onclick="inputData()">Обучить</button>
<hr>
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите свой возраст" id="myAge">
<br>
<button onclick="myMaturity()">Узнать свою зрелость</button>
```